# Is it possible to get Fedex ship history of particular tracking number using Fedex API

Tags: soap, soapui, fedex

Is it possible to get Fedex `ship(tracking) history of particular tracking number using Fedex SOAP API`. If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes fedex provide that services as 'Tracking service'.
https://www.fedex.com/en-us/developer/web-services/process.html
in standard services tab find track shipment services for different language.

You can track shipment in two ways

1)Track by tracking number

2)Track by reference number